# getFirebaseAdmin from next-firebase-auth causing TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js

I'm using the following package [next-firebase-auth](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth#getfirebaseadmin--firebaseadmin) and I'm calling `getFirebaseAdmin` from next-firebase-auth and when I try to use it I get the following error when I try to use db as a reference in `doc(db)`.

> Argument of type 'Firestore' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference'.
> Type 'Firestore' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentReference': converter, type, firestore, id, and 3
> more.

API

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getFirebaseAdmin } from "next-firebase-auth";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export const getUserInfo = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const db = getFirebaseAdmin().firestore();
 
  const docRef = doc(db, "user", "SF");
  return res.status(200).json({ data: "hello" });
};
```

Do I need to use init?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `db` instance to retrieve the doc directly with `db.collection("user").doc("SF")`.

You also have to call [`init`](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth#initconfig) before using `getFirebaseAdmin`. From the `next-firebase-auth` documentation:

> Initializes `next-firebase-auth`, taking a [config](https://github.com/gladly-team/next-firebase-auth#config) object. Must be called
> before calling any other method.

```js
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { init, getFirebaseAdmin } from "next-firebase-auth";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

init({/* your init config here */});

export const getUserInfo = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const db = getFirebaseAdmin().firestore();
 
  const docRef = db.collection("user").doc("SF");
  return res.status(200).json({ data: "hello" });
};
```

Comment: Yes I am calling the init function from import { init } from "next-firebase-auth"; What I had to do to get it to work was use V8 syntax not V9 syntax for firestore. Which is odd because  next-firebase-auth give an option for V9+ yarn add next-firebase-auth@canary which is what I'm using and looks like it doesn't support getFirebaseAdmin() v9.